# Visual Studio 2013 update 3, Designer won't load

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, xaml-designer

I have the following situation. I installed Visual Studio Update 3 last night. Now I have a problem that when I open my projects (Universal Apps) which i have done while i had update 2, my designer won't load and it throws an exception:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this? I guess this is not a bug because probably everything was tested by Microsoft, and this is not RC update. Im about to delete this update if i don't figure out the solution. I'm guessing that it might have to do with xaml if anything changed?

Comment: Well it does look like a bug. Since it talks "remoting", maybe a permissions/admin rights issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't work :)
And i can compile the up and everything looks fine. I just don't see Designer showing up in VS.

Comment: i am having same issue, i reported this to MS - you can up the rating here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/939281/blend-designer-crashes-after-installing-vs-2013-update-3-rtm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out from the connect bulletin that there are two folders in your Windows profile that need to have their contents cleared out in order for the Visual Studio designer to work with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

The two folders are:

For Blend: AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Blend\ShadowCache

For Visual Studio 2013: AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache

Don't delete these folders, just delete the content of those folders and you will be back to working happily with the XAML designer again.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the ShadowCache did not resolve this for me. Found a clue from an MSDN article and checked the event viewer for exceptions, look for XDesProc.exe.

The problem was an out of date driver for my graphics card.

Once that was updated all started working again

Comment: Nice, if ever cleaning ShadowCache doesn't work for me i will try that. Thanks for sharing!