# XAML Designer Failed to load

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop a Windows Phone app and I am using `Visual Studio 2013 Update 4` for development.

I am using `Pivot App (Windows Phone)` for development.

My problem is, `XAML` designer failed to load. I did some search on `StackOverflow` and `Google` and found some solutions and none of them worked.

The solutions I tried so far are :

- Repair of a `Visual Studio`.
- Clearing Contents in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache` (Answered [here on `StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134726/visual-studio-2013-update-3-designer-wont-load)
- Deleting `ComponentModelCache` from `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`

and none of these worked.

Please help me if anyone have solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the architecture to x86?

Comment: I Visual Studio, on top, there is a drop down menu and currently it is set to `Any CPU`, from there select `x86`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Tried. But not working